# Integrity for mixture of encrypted/unencrypted database fields

Tags: signature, authentication, hmac, integrity, database

I have multiple blobs each (symmetrically) encrypted with its own randomly generated key.

Now I want to encrypt these *blob keys* with *user keys* and store them in a database.

A table could have the following columns:

- `blob_id`
- `user_id` *(unencrypted)*
- `blob_key` *(encrypted with user key)*
- `expiry` *(unencrypted)*

Now I would like to ensure integrity and authenthicity of the *unencrypted* fields (for *encrypted* fields this is ensured using HMAC). Unencrypted data is quite short (in this case a key id and a date).

The use case is a large-scale E2EE encrypted cloud storage. So it should be massively scalable!

What is the best way to achieve this? Is it a good idea to use the *same* user key used for encryption also for signing the unencrypted fields? Which algorithm would you suggest for this type of data?

Comment: This is a complex question. You should mention the possible scenarios. Do you consider the row deletion/insertion attacks? Dou you consider the roll-back attack?

Comment: Each row is used to grant access to a block to a single user. So making sure a single unencrypted field is not changed is the point of this question. Inserting full entries doesn't matter since (`blob_id`,`user_id`) should be unique and `blob_key` is protected already. Deleting a row basically removes access to this blob for a single user, but I can't imagine a way to protect for this (except for redundancy) in case someone gains access to the database.

Comment: Roll-back attacks for `expiry` shouldn't matter too much either, since one can't travel into the past in order to restore an expired entry. Roll-back attacks for `user_id` basically restore removed access for a user. So this should be avoided if possible although the user could still have stored the decrypted `blob_key` on his computer while he still had access. Is there a good way to protect against this without re-encypting the blob with a new key?

Comment: Well, each of the attacks can have a solution up to some degree. One can protect the row just by the integrity since one has already encrypted data there. I don't see a need for the HMAC there. The Insertion can be prohibited by chain Hash/HMAC and keeping the last chain in the application server. This can also be used to detect deletion. For the freshness, Merle tree is the beast, however, the last chain can be also a solution if the application server data is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I always learn so much from your comments/answers! I added the use case to the question: large-scale E2EE encrypted sharable cloud file storage. So I guess chaining would be too much of a performance overhead and the risk is acceptable as I was describing. It would still be nice to protect against changes in the `expiry` field.

Comment: A row-based solution will be enough then. Add another column that stores the HMAC of the other rows.

Comment: I agree, but beware it is still possible to use the fields without HMAC verification the way the question is currently stated.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes What do you meen by "it is still possible"?

Comment: Oh, I just meant that if you store a HMAC value in a separate field that you are more likely to accidentally use the fields without verifying the MAC. If you store them in a binary field together with the value then this is less likely to happen, but you'd be sacrificing some convenience.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I need to store it in a separate field to be able to index and search on the single fields. My goal is to implement a proxy similar to [MIT's CryptDB](http://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/) which adds support for HMAC and unencrypted fields. For my specific application, I still have to think which fields could be encrypted deterministically without breaking functionality and introducing too many round-trips for lookup between client and server.